# How to make a moving GameObject push a CharacterController smoothly?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a GameObject called **Player** with a CharacterController component attached that has the following settings.

[image]

**Player** also has a script called `PlayerController` attached. 
Gravity is applied to the CharacterController through the following function, which is called in `Update()`.

```
private void ApplyGravity()
{
    if (!characterController.isGrounded)
    {
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

The **Player** has a child GameObject called **PlayerModel** which just has a default CapsuleCollider attached.

The `PlayerController` has an additional function called `MoveAround()`, which is also called in `Update()`; incase this is related to the issue.

```
public void MoveAround()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = playerInputActions.Player.Move.ReadValue<Vector2>();

    currentInput = new Vector2(moveInput.y, moveInput.x);

    float moveDirectionY = moveDirection.y;

    float speed = isSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed;

    moveDirection = (transform.forward * currentInput.x + transform.right * currentInput.y) + boatController.boatRigidbody.velocity;

    moveDirection.y = moveDirectionY;

    moveDirection.Normalize();

    moveDirection *= speed;
}
```

I have a GameObject called **Boat**, which has a default BoxCollider, Rigidbody and `BoatController` script attached;
the Rigidbody has the following settings.

[image]

The **Boat** is floating on water, therefore moving up and down. 
 The **Player** is resting on the surface of the **Boat**. 
When the **Boat** floats up, the **Player** is pushed upwards with it. When it floats back down, the `ApplyGravity()` function is called, bringing the **Player** back down with it.

The Scene setup looks like this.
[image]

> The problem is this process is not smooth. 
>  The
> **Player** jitters at the collision point when being pushed up, and when falling back down.

I have attempted trying to snap the **Player** position to the surface of the **Boat**, however this causes the same issue. 
Building on from that, I have also tried using the combination of `Physics.Raycast()` and `Vector3.Lerp()` to grab the surface position and smoothly move the **Player** to that position respectively; this caused some strange bugs (but I could've implemented it incorrectly).

Any advice on how to solve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best way to handle a character on any sort of moving platform is to make the character object a child of whatever it is standing on.

That way, movements of the platform will perfectly translate into movements of the character.

Just remember to unparent them when the character is no longer supported by the platform.